# How to horizontally center text on Codename One in GUI Builder?

Tags: codenameone

I think there is no equivalent of "Text Align: center" in the properties exposed in the GUI builder? Can't find of a way to do it.

(playing with the Border Layouts, I can place a Label in the center cell, but its text remains left aligned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think alignment is currently supported in the GUI builder styling UI. It's probably something that should be there (please file an RFE).

I think you saw the "text position" property which positions the text relatively to the icon. Currently the only way to control alignment is via the standard theme/style options.

Answer (score 1):

I have just added support for setting text alignment in the GUI builder style editor.  This will be available in the next plugin update.